# C# method to do URL encoding?

Tags: c#, http, encoding, character-encoding

what c# class method can I use to URL encode a URL string?

In my use case I want to pass a URL string as a URL parameter itself.  So like burying a URL within a URL.  Without some encoding the "&" and "?" characters in the inner URL can get picked up when the parameters for the outer Url parameters are processed

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461223/how-do-i-encode-an-url

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)

Comment: UrlEncode() and UrlPathEncode() do not encode all special characters.

Answer (score 13):

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(str)
```

Comment: This method doesn't exists (There are `HtmlEncode` and `HtmlDecode` only).

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx)

Its .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: This is actually a very good solution since it does not have a dependency on System.Web and can also be used in PCLs.

Answer (score 5):

[`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode.aspx) might be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use Server.UrlEncode

You need an instance of the HttpServerUtility class, because the UrlEncode method is not static.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: I get an error Error... The type 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility' has no constructors defined. How do you new it up then?

Answer (score 0):

I am operating with .net framework 2.0. But it never shows me "UrlEncode" intelisense when I place dot after httpserverutility. Here are the options I see:

```
HttpServerUtility.Equals 
HttpServerUtility.ReferenceEquals
HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode
HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode
```

That's it, these are the only options I see. Could I possibly ask for small piece of code as an example to use url encode function?

Thanks,

Linda