# ASP.NET MVC hash sign ignored in parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple list of programming languages stored in a database, such as, C#, Java, F# etc. and these are listed in a razor view. To see the detail of it when then url like ...\language\java works but for ...\language\C# and ...\language\C# did not work.

The hash sign (#) is ignored and in Action the id parameter is "C" instead of "C#" and "F" instead of "F#".

Here is the code

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Languages)
{
    <li>
        <a href="/Language/@item.Title">@item.Title</a>
    </li>
}
```

When click on the link then it will call Detail Action in Language controller with parameter such as java, C# etc. But in action method I get id="C" instead if "C#"

Can you please help me how to handle this scenario.

Comment: how are you displaying the URL? From the model to direct `HREF`? or are you using  `@Html.ActionLink` or  `Url.Action` ?

Comment: can you post the razor code your currently have?

Comment: The `#` is a fragment identifier and the browser does not send anything in a url after the `#` symbol (consider using `../language/CSharp` instead)

Comment: `To see the detail of it when then url like ...\language\java works but for ...\language\C# and ...\language\C# did not work.` Please show us that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# method to do URL encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506873/c-sharp-method-to-do-url-encoding)

Comment: Try encode the `#` sign in URL into `%23`, e.g. `C%23` or `F%23` as in SO URL for `C#` tag.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Added code to my initial comment

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas Use `Html.ActionLink` to generate links, it will encode the url when needed. Please see my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47745939/6577199)

Answer (score 1):

You need to url encode some chaacters (such as #), you need to pass %23 for #

Check here all encodings https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use HtmlHelper or UrlHelper to generate action urls, they will help to encode the characters when needed

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Languages)
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(item, "Detail", "Language", new { id = item }, null)
    </li>
}
```

Comment: That will not work! Anything after the `#` is not sent to the server

Comment: @StephenMuecke The `#` will be encoded into `%23` in the query string, e.g. `language?name=C%23`
If there are other parameters, the query string will be like `language?name=C%23&p1=111&p2=222...`

Comment: Yes, but OP is generating `../language/C#` in the address bar. You cannot assume that a user will only ever navigate by clicking a link

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sent to server .
Use CSharp or FSharp instead of C# or F#