# How to encode a URL string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string that contains a url which looks like this:

http://www.test.com/images/tony's pics.jpg

I need the url to look like this:

http://www.test.com/images/tony%27s%20pics.jpg

How would I programmatically solve this with a url in a STRING form.  Thanks.

Comment: See this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp/575843#575843

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461223/how-do-i-encode-an-url ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would think this would easily be solved by using the HttpUtility UrlEncode:

```
string url = "http://www.test.com/images/" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("tony's pics.jpg");
```

Comment: This is going to result in http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%2fsearch%3fq%3dExample

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [at UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) of the HttpServerUtility:

```
HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.test.com/images/tony's pics.jpg");
```

Comment: This is going to result in http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%2fsearch%3fq%3dExample